# language option supported in listings

Tags: listings, javascript

I am afraid that listing doesn't support javascript.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=javascript]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is no language support for javaSCRIPT

Comment: thanks. but it's disappointing, that it doesn't, while it supports even php.

Comment: I can highly recommend the [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package, but it does require [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) and its `pygmentize` command. Also, to be able to call that command, your LaTeX will require the `--shell-escape` option.

Comment: This is an attempt to create a javaScript listing for ES6, Node.js, Express.js, Jasmine etc. into: https://github.com/xgirma/latex-javaScript

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is Fran's example, based on the cited (now defunct) source:

```
% Taken from Lena Herrmann at 
% http://lenaherrmann.net/2010/05/20/javascript-syntax-highlighting-in-the-latex-listings-package
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

\lstset{
   language=JavaScript,
   backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
   extendedchars=true,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showspaces=false,
   numbers=left,
   numberstyle=\footnotesize,
   numbersep=9pt,
   tabsize=2,
   breaklines=true,
   showtabs=false,
   captionpos=b
}



\begin{document}

\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=My Javascript Example]
Name.prototype = {
  methodName: function(params){
    var doubleQuoteString = "some text";
    var singleQuoteString = 'some more text';
    // this is a comment
    if(this.confirmed != null && typeof(this.confirmed) == Boolean && this.confirmed == true){
      document.createElement('h3');
      $('#system').append("This looks great");
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Error;
    }
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: @commonhare, I was doing my answer based on this site but you have ahead, so just add an the example to your answers, as suggest Thorsen.

Comment: Now that the link is dead, I'm glad the entire example was included. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to highlight ?s, but adding it as a keyword didn't work. I was able to highlight it by adding `moredelim=**[il][\mdseries{\color{blue}?}\mdseries]{?},`. Seems to work with multiple questions marks (`object?.maybeAttribute?.value`), as well as not highlighting in comments (`// this won't be blue?`)

Answer (score 19):

I merged the answers of @awx and @commonhare to get this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Geruhn/3d21f60a869457373d84):

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, false, finally, for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, null, return, switch, this, throw, true, try, typeof, var, void, while, with},
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  sensitive=true
}

\lstset{
   language=JavaScript,
   backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
   extendedchars=true,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showspaces=false,
   numbers=left,
   numberstyle=\footnotesize,
   numbersep=9pt,
   tabsize=2,
   breaklines=true,
   showtabs=false,
   captionpos=b
}
```

Comment: Note: it seems that `ndkeywords` is deprecated: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf (page 44)

Answer (score 9):

The currently accepted answer misses a lot of keywords, so here's my language definition:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, finally, for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, return, switch, this, throw, try, typeof, var, void, while, with},
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  sensitive=true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the `\lstset` at the beginning of the each files(chapter1.tex - C code, chapter2.tex - Matlab code) with following setting:

```
\lstset{ %
  language=C,                            % choose the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,              % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{White},         % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  commentstyle=\color{help}\textit,
  keywordstyle=\color{keyword}\textbf,
  breaklines=true,                       % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,                % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  showspaces=false,                      % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=true,                 % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=true,                         % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=none,                              % adds a frame around the code - none, single
  tabsize=8,                             % sets default tabsize to 8 spaces
  captionpos=b,                          % sets the caption-position to bottom
  numbers=left,                          % where to put the line-numbers -none, left, right
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,             % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                          % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1 each line
                                         % will be numbered
}
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

A complete keyword list which also covers typescript would be:

```
keywords={abstract, any, as, boolean, break, case, catch, class, console, 
    const, continue, debugger, declare, default, delete, do, else, enum, export, 
    extends, false, finally, for, from, function, get, if, implements, import, in, 
    infer, instanceof, interface, keyof, let, module, namespace, never, new, null, 
    number, object, package, private, protected, public, readonly, require, return, 
    set, static, string, super, switch, symbol, this, throw, true, try, type, typeof, 
    undefined, unique, unknown, var, void, while, with, yield}
```