# Pandoc: Markdown to PDF, without cutting off code block lines that are too long

Tags: line-breaking, pdf, pandoc, markdown

I'm trying to convert a Markdown file into a PDF file using Pandoc.

I have a lot of code blocks in my Markdown, and if I have a line of code that is too long, it will just be cut off in the PDF. How can I make Pandoc wrap lines that are too long?

Here's the line I'm using right now:

```
pandoc input.md --highlight-style tango -o output.pdf;
```

Comment: You should report this as a bug / feature request. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues

Comment: It was reported as a bug / feature request here : https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4302

Comment: [This lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/minted) could be an option.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

(See **Update** at the end, to get proper colors)

By default pandoc uses its own highlighting engine, but it can be changed to use package `listings` instead. Simply add `--listings` option to your pandoc command line.

However, the format used by listings does not break long lines either, but you can prepare all the required options in a separate tex file, for example:

```
% Contents of listings-setup.tex
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    stepnumber=2,
    numbersep=5pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    linewidth=\textwidth
}
```

And then compile with the line:

```
pandoc test.md --listings -H listings-setup.tex -o output.pdf
```

Unfortunately, this solution cannot use the `--highlight-style` option too. If you want to get the `tango` colorscheme, you have to code it yourself as options for the listing packages, and include them in the `\lstset` above.

Given the file `test.md` as follows:

````
% Title
% Author

# First section

Some code with long lines:

```java
public class Test {
    static Set<Thread> updateThreads = new HashSet<Thread>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            startUpdateThread(i, concurrentMap);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : concurrentMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key :" + entry.getKey() + " Value:" + entry.getValue());
        }
        for (Thread thread : updateThreads) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

That's it.
````

The result generated by the previous pandoc command line is:

> [image: Output]

## Update

In order to mimic closely the result obtained with `--highlight-style tango` option (and no `listings` package), I ran pandoc asking for the intermediate `.tex` file to discover how the colors were defined for that case.

I wrote the following setup using `listings` options, which use the same colors (only where applicable, for example `listings` has no mean to set a specific color for numeric constants or other syntactic elements). In addition I reduced the spacing among chars, which were too far apart with default setup. This is the new setup:

```
% Contents of listings-setup.tex
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}\itshape,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{248,248,248},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    linewidth=\textwidth,
    basewidth=0.5em,
}
```

Using those settings, i.e. running `pandoc` with options:

```
pandoc test.md --listings -H listings-setup.tex -o output.pdf
```

the following result is obtained:

[image: Result with listings]

For reference, compare it with the result without `--listings` but with `--highlight-syntax tango` instead:

[image: Without listings]

As you can see, the style is very close (except for numeric constants, which are blue using `tango`, but black using `listings`). Note also how the lines were wrapped with `listings`. I also added line numbers which refer to the original lines (before wrapping).

Comment: I added "--latex-engine=xelatex" and it works! What's the easiest way to add back some syntax highlight to the code?

Comment: I managed to get some highlight using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89574/language-option-supported-in-listings but it doesn't look great. Are there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: @pimpampoum Look at the updated answer.

Comment: One may want to add `showlines=true` to avoid trailing newlines being cut off. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588916/461834

Comment: This works, but it will not just fail on numbers when it comes to highlighting, but also classes and global objects (i.e. `console` in JavaScript). I wish the syntax highlighting would be better. `stringstyle` also fails on JavaScript and `identifierstyle` would match too much (I was hoping it would help here, but it's not).

Comment: Can you take a look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618658/which-extent-of-latex-functionality-packages-is-available-in-pandoc ?

Answer (score 9):

There is a really simple solution, using [fvextra](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra), recently [suggested by jannick0](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4302#issuecomment-360669013).

Modify your [YAML header options](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) to include

```
\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

and compile with xelatex.

For instance,

```
---
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{fvextra}
 - \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---

~~~~~{.java}
this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken
~~~~~~
```

when compiled with

```
pandoc input.md -o output.pdf
```

gives [image]

Comment: Given that using lstlistings has a number of side-effects, this is surely a less invasive solution.

Comment: One can also add `breakanywhere` to make it also break long lines with no spaces, like:
`\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,commandchars=\\\{\}}`

Comment: This works much better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

One does not need a listings-setup.tex in order for this to work.

Just add this to your YAML-Header include:

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{xcolor}
    - \lstset{breaklines=true}
    - \lstset{language=[Motorola68k]Assembler}
    - \lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
    - \lstset{extendedchars=true}
    - \lstset{tabsize=2}
    - \lstset{columns=fixed}
    - \lstset{showstringspaces=false}
    - \lstset{frame=trbl}
    - \lstset{frameround=tttt}
    - \lstset{framesep=4pt}
    - \lstset{numbers=left}
    - \lstset{numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily}
    - \lstset{postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}}
```

and compile with `--listings`.
If there are compile errors try to add `--pdf-engine=xelatex` or `--pdf-engine=lualatex`.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an apostille to Clement's  (ihmo best) solution  that cannot be illustrated in a comment. The highlight can be fixed  in the YAML header. On the other hand, the lines of code can be numbered passing the option `.numberLines` to the code chunk:

Example stealing the code of JLDiaz's answer:

---

[image: mwe]

---

````
---
classoption: twocolumn # for more code line breaks
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
output:
  pdf_document: 
    highlight: tango
---

# First section

Some code with long lines:


```{.java .numberLines}

public class Test {
    static Set<Thread> updateThreads = new HashSet<Thread>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            startUpdateThread(i, concurrentMap);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : concurrentMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key :" + entry.getKey() + " Value:" + entry.getValue());
        }
        for (Thread thread : updateThreads) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}

```
That's it.
````

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* want to add line breaks and **not modify the rest of the default code blocks layout**, you can use [hda's method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314287) in a simplified version, and modified to keep the original font spacing thanks to [decrease monotype letter spacing in lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568584/decrease-monotype-letter-spacing-in-lstlisting).

TL;DR: Add this on top of your .md file:

```
---
header-includes:
    - \lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, basewidth=0.5em}
    - \lstset{breaklines=true}
---
```

and compile it with:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf --listings
```