# Add a black border to block quotations?

Tags: framed, quoting, pandoc, markdown

I have a Markdown file that I'm converting to PDF with Pandoc. And I'd like that the block quotation of the Markdown file get a 1px black border around them in the PDF.

I already managed to edit the style of code blocks with \lstset, but I'm not sure how to do the same for block quotations.

Answer (score 13):

Following a similar technique than the one in [Pandoc: Markdown to PDF, without cutting off code block lines that are too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179926/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf-without-cutting-off-code-block-lines-that-are-too-long) you can write a file named, for example `quote-setup.tex` containing:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\let\oldquote=\quote
\let\endoldquote=\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{framed}\begin{oldquote}}{\end{oldquote}\end{framed}}
```

and compile with:

```
pandoc example.md -H quote-setup.tex -o example.pdf
```

IMHO, the frame is "too agressive" visually. I would prefer a more subtle effect such as a shaded background. This can be achieved with:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\oldquote=\quote
\let\endoldquote=\endquote
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{shaded*}\begin{oldquote}}{\end{oldquote}\end{shaded*}}
```

So, for example:

```
# Example section

Now, a quote:

> Proin iaculis tellus sed fringilla elementum. Suspendisse porta tincidunt magna. 
> Mauris cursus pharetra lacinia. Mauris ac auctor nibh. Duis laoreet scelerisque 
> leo, ac pellentesque lorem feugiat tempus. In eu rhoncus velit. Ut bibendum nibh
> ut feugiat semper.
```

will produce:

[image: Result]

Comment: How can I decrease the amount of empty space around the text?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267960/52459 says to use the `tcolorbox` package to reduce empty space.