# Reducing upper and lower margin in shaded environment

Tags: margins, framed, shading

I am using `\begin{shaded}` from `\usepackage{framed}` to highlight some formulae and theorems in some notes I am writing.

I would like to reduce the upper and lower margin: how can I do it?

Comment: 1. Ask for help by providing a complete example. 2. Try setting `\FrameSep` to a different value. 3. Try using a different package, such as `tcolorbox` or `adjustbox` or ....

Comment: @jon Thank you! Changing the setting of `\FrameSep` I managed to fix the issue!

Comment: @jon Please write an answer.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- Done. (Tried to expand on my three points slightly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is virtually always better to provide a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)), but here are two very different possibilities.

For reasons that are hopefully obvious from the examples themselves, `tcolorbox` adds a lot more flexibility, but is a correspondingly bigger and more complex package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed, lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{framed}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{framed}
\lipsum[3]

\clearpage
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{framed}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{framed}
\lipsum[3]

\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[3]

\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
% Too many options to list; but see especially
% sections 4.7.4, 4.10, 4.15, 4.16
% For example, an unwise setting:
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=0mm, bottom=15mm, left=18mm, right=3mm]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[3]

% These settings could be given to a new tcolorbox for repeated use: 
% \newtcolorbox{examplebox}{top=0mm, bottom=15mm, left=18mm, right=3mm}
% \begin{examplebox}
%  \lipsum[2]
% \end{examplebox} 
\end{document}
```