# decrease monotype letter spacing in lstlisting

Tags: fonts, listings, letterspacing

I'm using listings to display code in my document and tgheros font. How can I decrease the monotype letter spacing for code listings?

```latex
% in my preamble
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tgheros}

% lstset definition
\lstset{language=Python,%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,%
    % [...]
}

% code
Python code below.

\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{lstlisting}
def function(variable):
    pass # monospace font spacing is too large
\end{lstlisting}
```

In the screenshot you can see that the letter spacing is quite high. How to decrease it while keeping a monospace font?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `basewidth` setting in your `lstset` definition:

```
\lstset{language=Python,%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,%
    basewidth=0.6em % default value
}
```

For example, `basewidth=0.6em` (default):

[image]

`basewidth=0.5em`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It was missing from this overleaf doc: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing#Options_to_customize_code_listing_styles but it's present in this one: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf