pandoc: markdown to pdf codeblock cutting of long lines (long strings not being correctly wrapped)
I want my code block to wrap, no matter what. Ideally
the code block
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
4
easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap
6
7


should become something like that:
1 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  000000000000000000000000000000000
2
3 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 
  333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
  333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
  33333333333333333333333333333
4 4
5 easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap 
  easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap 
  easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap 
  easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap 
  easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap easy wrap
6 6
7 7
8

I have tried everything in
Pandoc: Markdown to PDF, without cutting off code block lines that are too long
and
Pandoc: code blocks in MarkDown with very long lines get cut off when outputting to PDF
and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238148/how-to-wrap-long-lines-inside-of-markdown-code-in-github-and-gitlab-issu but I refuse to put some random css into my human readable markdown.
But all of these fail with the zeros and threes. It only wraps the easy wraps.
This seems like something that might be the correct approach, but I have very little idea of what am I doing here so I would appreciate someone showing me how I could translate this into something I can use with pandoc: Breaking lines resulting from \mintinline or \Verb

Because (some of) your long lines do not have whitespaces, you should remove option breakatwhitespace=true from, e.g., the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179926/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf-without-cutting-off-code-block-lines-that-are-too-long. See the listings documentation for more information.

@cabohah I tried removing the line from the updated top answer, but still no luck. Regarding breakatwhitespace the docs don't really say anything except If true, it allows line breaks only at white space. Which would be great. (Also tried setting it false explicitly, but no luck)
Maybe I'm running the command wrong? pandoc test.md --listings -H listings-setup.tex  -o test.pdf where listings-setup.tex contains the stuff from the linked post.
